# ASP.NET MVC Single Sign ON Authentication for multiple MVC applications deployed in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, single-sign-on

We have multiple websites using ASP.NET MVC deployed in Azure.

Consider each portal URLs are like this ( site1.azurewebsites.net, site2.azurewebsites.net, site3.cloudapp.net). Each URL has their login page with their own DB for login authentication. We have complete control of DB and site application URLs.

We want to add one single common URL for authenticating the user in all 3 systems and provide links to enable / disable access respective site URLs with out asking them to login again.

Please advise the approach to implement Single Sign On to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

---

> We want to add one single common URL for authenticating the user in all 3 systems.

If you have many web applications in origination and they interreact with each other, you can implement single sign-on multiple applications in that case you can use Azure AD. In Azure AD users can access multiple applications with a single sign On.

> provide links to enable / disable access respective site URLs with out asking them to login again.

In azure active directory you can not enable/disable from programmatically . you have to use portal to enable/disable uses.

The following documents will help you to implement the Azure AD sign-in web application.

[Add Sign-in with Microsoft to a web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet-core) by Microsoft documents
[Web app that signs in users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-overview?tabs=aspnetcore&view=aspnetcore-6.0) by Microsoft documents

Comment: Thank you for the response, We cannot not use Azure AD. Since these are customer portals and their logins are specific to system or portal. I tried to add one common URL for Login authentication. Once login is success by validating with 3 portals DB and then enable / disable respective portal links. But the way to pass the authenticated data to specific  URLs is where i need some advise. I looked at some references from Web by using cookie based authentication using same Machine key setup in all 3 portals web.config file but not sure whether it works for azurewebsites.net.

Comment: Is there any other  approaches where i can add all 3 URLs specific projects add it as part of the common URL project by taking out the login screen options in all 3 portals once authenticated provide access the specific portal links.